# Not able to change dir in linux using cd

Tags: linux

Hye Everyone,

Thanks in advance, Can anyone tell me why cd is not working with var. Is their any other solution to change directory as a variable in Linux in bash scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(pm2 l | grep online | grep 7701 | awk ' { print $2 } ')
echo $current
stop=$(pm2 l | grep stopped | grep 7701 | awk ' { print $2 } ')
echo $stop
wrk=$(pm2 show $stop | grep  cwd | awk ' { print $5 } ' )
pwd
export wrk="$(pm2 show $stop | grep  cwd | awk ' { print $5 } ' )"
echo $wrk
cd $wrk    (**Not working** )
```

Comment: Normally it should work, did you verify if the value is correct?

Comment: Try quoting `"` your variables e.g `"$wrk"`

Comment: *Not working* says little, what error do you actually get? anyway you should check if the directory exists, check the permissions and as already said, quote the variable.

Comment: @sohan Dogra - As you have plenty of output from your script, it would be wise to share it.